# doubts on hashcode implementation in java

Tags: java

i would very thankful if you can clear my doubt
suppose i have a class A and B
A has the reference of B say b1 and b2.
as in class A overrides the equal method something like the 
   b1.equal(other.b1) and b2.equal(other.b2)

and override the hashcode method something like

```
int result = 1;
result = 17* result + ((b1== null) ? 0 : b1.hashCode());
result = 17* result + ((b2== null) ? 0 : b2.hashCode());
return result;
```

is my hashcode method is correctly implemented?
and also if i am calling b1.hashcode() then it will also call the hashcode method of class B?
if yes, then it compulsory to override the equals and hashcode in class B?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code quality and belongs on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

The *only* requirement of `hashCode()` in Java is consistency. That means that two identical instances of `A` *must* return the same hash code. If your code does this, then you are technically good. This means that technically a `hashCode()` function that is simply `return 1` is valid. Obviously though, it is a bad implementation because it has a 100% collision rate. So in order to make a good `hashCode` function, you should also minimize your collision rate.

With that being said, your code looks good.

Comment: +1, but slight tweak: the only requirement for _functional correctness_ is that equal objects have the same hashcode. Performance is a real requirement, even if it's not formalized in an API. Always returning `0` from hashCode is correct in the same way that always sorting with bubble sort is correct; functionally it is, but it's not usable in most situations in practice.

Comment: Yes, you are right, performance is always important.

Answer (score 1):

This looks correct. Yes, you should override the hashCode and equals methods of class B also.

Comment: Override the equals and hashCode methods in class B if, and only if, the implementations they would inherit are not appropriate. If B extends Object directly, that means if two distinct B instances be equal.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan We can see that the OP expects to override equals in B (see `b1.equal(other.b1)` in question). If he does, then it is mandatory to override hashCode as well in order to maintain the correct semantics -- so I think we agree.

Comment: Yes, if B needs to declare an equals method, rather than inheriting from its superclass, it is very, very important to override hashCode to match.

Comment: as in B class if equal method is not override then my above code will work fine?

Comment: @Dev The code will also be fine if you override neither `hashCode` nor `equals` in class B.  The default implementations with object identity are fine in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, though it could be simplified to:

```
 int result = ((b1== null) ? 0 : b1.hashCode());
 result = 17* result + ((b2== null) ? 0 : b2.hashCode());
 return result;
```

Comment: Hardly any simplification in there.

Comment: One line less. You could actually take out another line by just doing `return 17* result + ((b2== null) ? 0 : b2.hashCode());`, but again this is just for vertical real estate. No real optimization going on here.

Comment: My point is that there's at least a reason to mix the hashcodes with a multiplier.  There is basically no point to A) start with a constant 1, B) multiply said constant by 17, which you could have just done by choosing a different constant nor C) adding a constant to the next value in the first place.  Basically: it doesn't simplify things much, it doesn't matter performance wise, but if the person wrote that by hand, he was being superfluously verbose.